# Retrieve the default calendar id in Android

Tags: android, calendar

I have the following code for adding event to calendar.

The problem is that I don't know how to retrieve the **default** calendar id.

```
long calID = 3;
long startMillis = 0; 
long endMillis = 0;     
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2013, 3, 23, 7, 30);
startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2013, 3, 24, 8, 45);
endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
values.put(Events.TITLE, "My Test");
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "My Calendar Test");
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "Israel/tel-aviv");
Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

The line: `long calID = 3;` is the calendar id

Is it possible to get the default calendar id from Android, or do I need to show a list of calendars and have the user pick one?

If not possible, how to show the list of calendar accounts?

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue ?? You can follow Malwinder Singh's answer to get the list of primary calendar IDs and we can use the calendar Id of any of those accounts for creating events. You can refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46965732/event-added-through-calendar-provider-is-not-showing-up-on-the-android-calendar

Answer (score 17):

To get the list of calendars, you need to query the ContentResolver like this:

```
public MyCalendar [] getCalendar(Context c) {

    String projection[] = {"_id", "calendar_displayName"};
    Uri calendars;
    calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");

    ContentResolver contentResolver = c.getContentResolver();
    Cursor managedCursor = contentResolver.query(calendars, projection, null, null, null);

    if (managedCursor.moveToFirst()){
        m_calendars = new MyCalendar[managedCursor.getCount()];
        String calName;
        String calID;
        int cont= 0;
        int nameCol = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[1]);
        int idCol = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
        do {
            calName = managedCursor.getString(nameCol);
            calID = managedCursor.getString(idCol);
            m_calendars[cont] = new MyCalendar(calName, calID);
            cont++;
        } while(managedCursor.moveToNext());
        managedCursor.close();
    }
    return m_calendars;

}
```

Comment: requires requires android.permission.READ_CALENDAR

Answer (score 9):

I used following code to get the calendar ID.

```
private fun getCalendarId(context: Context) : Long? {
    val projection = arrayOf(Calendars._ID, Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME)

    var calCursor = context.contentResolver.query(
        Calendars.CONTENT_URI,
        projection,
        Calendars.VISIBLE + " = 1 AND " + Calendars.IS_PRIMARY + "=1",
        null,
        Calendars._ID + " ASC"
    )

    if (calCursor != null && calCursor.count <= 0) {
        calCursor = context.contentResolver.query(
            Calendars.CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            Calendars.VISIBLE + " = 1",
            null,
            Calendars._ID + " ASC"
        )
    }

    if (calCursor != null) {
        if (calCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val calName: String
            val calID: String
            val nameCol = calCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[1])
            val idCol = calCursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0])

            calName = calCursor.getString(nameCol)
            calID = calCursor.getString(idCol)

            Log.d("Calendar name = $calName Calendar ID = $calID")

            calCursor.close()
            return calID.toLong()
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

So do not pass 0, 1 or 3 as Calendar ID. Use above function instead.

Also, check if Calendar ID is `null` and do not perform operations with it if it is `null`.

```
        val calendarId = getCalendarId(context)
        if (calendarId != null) {
        //Call operations e.g.: Insert operation
        }
```

Comment: If there are multiple primary entries, then probably we can use the calendar ID of any of those entries to create events right ??

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy There might be multiple primary entries if multiple accounts are registered on the device. So that depends on which account you want to use.

Answer (score 7):

There's a [`IS_PRIMARY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarColumns.html#IS_PRIMARY) column in `CalendarContract.CalendarColumns`. You query with selection:

```
CalendarContract.CalendarColumns.IS_PRIMARY + "=1"
```

However, this is since SDK 17

Comment: Sorry for late post, this might be useful for future followers. It seems the IS_PRIMARY attribute is not unique. I have several accounts on my calendar list (university, private, work) and they all seem to be marked as primary. The only ones who are not primary are the birthdays and holidays. (I ran the above code to verify).

Comment: Yes i also have 2 accounts signed into my device. so i'm getting 2 entries marked as primary.

Answer (score 4):

Some latest versions have issue, there is different visible calendar list so below is the code to select PRIMARY calendar and in older devices this query return 0 record, so used second one if 1st one return 0 records.

```
Cursor calCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI, projection, CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE + " = 1 AND "  + CalendarContract.Calendars.IS_PRIMARY + "=1", null, CalendarContract.Calendars._ID + " ASC");
if(calCursor.getCount() <= 0){
    calCursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI, projection, CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE + " = 1", null, CalendarContract.Calendars._ID + " ASC");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as a default calendar.
A device could have **multiple primary calendars**! You have to list the calendars that are primary and the user has the write access. In the editing dialog, add an extra field to let the user select the desired account. Save the specified account somewhere (like preferences). Next time when the user wants to add a new event use that value as the default account.
Just remember `calID` may change in time. It is better to keep a mixture of both `ACCOUNT_NAME` and `ACCOUNT_TYPE` as unique identifier.
Also its possible that user removes the account from the device, So each time user wants to make a new event, you have to check whether that saved account excited or not

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me

```
private fun calendarId(): Long? {
    val uri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI
    var cursor: Cursor?= null

    //Submit calendar query
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        cursor = contentResolver?.query(uri, CALENDAR_PROJECTION, null, null, null)

    } else{
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR), PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_CALENDAR) }

     if (cursor != null) {
         Log.d("MainActivity", "Cursor is present")
         if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             //Get required fields
             val calID = cursor.getLong(CAL_ID)
             val calName = cursor.getLong(CAL_NAME)
             Log.d("MainActivity", "Calendar ID: $calID, Calendar Name: $calName")
             cursor.close()
             return calID
         }
     }

    //return null
    return null
}
```