# How add mutiple events to calendar without intent Android 8 or >?

Tags: android, calendar

I have already found questions about this but for my case nothing is happening.
[Event added through Calendar Provider is not showing up on the Android Calendar App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46965732/event-added-through-calendar-provider-is-not-showing-up-on-the-android-calendar)
I try to follow this but obviously I missed something since it doesn't work

I want to add several events in the calendar.
I'm already trying with 1 but nothing happens

I am currently under android 10

```
    public void addEventToCalendar(){

        long calID = 3;
        long startMillis = 0;
        long endMillis = 0;
        Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        beginTime.set(2021, 10, 22, 15, 30);
        startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
        Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        endTime.set(2021, 10, 22, 16, 45);
        endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

        ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Hackathon");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "do some code");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
        
        long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
    }
```

Comment: There is no requirement for every calendar app to use `CalendarContract`. Calendar apps can store their data wherever and however they wish.

Comment: Well, this is not a good news, Do you have any solution for that ?@CommonsWare

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "any solution". There are hundreds of calendar apps. Some will use `CalendarContract` for storing calendar events, and others will not. Similarly, there are hundreds of contact manager apps -- some of those will use `ContactsContract` for storing contact details, and others will not.

Comment: @CommonsWare, the ting is, I don't want to create calendar app, I just want to insert some events.

Comment: "I just want to insert some events" -- you assume that the calender app that the user wants to use supports some way for third-party apps to insert some events. Your approach with `CalendarContract` is fine, but you need to test with some calendar app that you *know* uses `CalendarContract`, and you need to accept that not all calendar use `CalendarContract`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Well, I think wanting to add events silently doesn't help either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put it on a class, I'm using a CSV file where I just add my differents events, it's working for me on differents devices android and tested on Oreo, Pie  and Android 10

```
    public class EventCalendar {
String startEvent;
String endEvent;
String title;
String description;

public String getStartEvent() {
    return startEvent;
}

public void setStartEvent(String startEvent) {
    this.startEvent = startEvent;
}

public String getEndEvent() {
    return endEvent;
}

public void setEndEvent(String endEvent) {
    this.endEvent = endEvent;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
    public void addEventCalendar(Context myContext, InputStream is) {
    List<EventCalendar> mesEvent = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    String line;
    try {
        reader.readLine();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.d("MyEventCalendar", "Line : " + line);
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            Date startDate;
            Date endDate;

            startDate = sdf.parse(tokens[0]);
            endDate = sdf.parse(tokens[1]);

            EventCalendar myEventCalendar = new EventCalendar();
            myEventCalendar.setTitle(tokens[2]);
            if (tokens.length >= 4){
                myEventCalendar.setDescription(tokens[3]);
            }else {
                myEventCalendar.setDescription(null);
            }

            myEventCalendar.setStartEvent(String.valueOf(startDate.getTime()));
            myEventCalendar.setEndEvent(String.valueOf(endDate.getTime()));
            mesEvent.add(myEventCalendar);

            ContentResolver cr = Objects.requireNonNull(myContext.getContentResolver());
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, myEventCalendar.getStartEvent());
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, myEventCalendar.getEndEvent());
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, myEventCalendar.getTitle());
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, myEventCalendar.getDescription());
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION,0);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
            Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

        }
    } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
        Log.i("Tag", "Insert failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```