# add event and reminder to android calendar programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I need to set a calendar event in my android app, I have try this code and it doesn't throw any error and I think it should works but when I check the calendar in my android device, the event not appear. This is the code :

```
public void addAppointmentsToCalender(Context context, String title, String desc, String place,  String appointmentDate){

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    try {

        Date eventDate = dateFormat.parse(appointmentDate);
        calendar.setTime(eventDate);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("Error Adding Event", "Error in adding event on calendar" + ex.getMessage());
    }

    String reminderDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
    Log.e("Day before event start", reminderDate);
    String reminderDayStart = reminderDate + " 00:00:00";
    String reminderDayEnd = reminderDate + " 23:59:59";
    long startTimeInMilliseconds = 0, endTimeInMilliseconds = 0;

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
        Date SDate = formatter.parse(reminderDayStart);
        Date EDate = formatter.parse(reminderDayEnd);
        startTimeInMilliseconds = SDate.getTime();
        endTimeInMilliseconds = EDate.getTime();
        Log.e("StartDate", startTimeInMilliseconds + " " + reminderDayStart);
        Log.e("EndDate", endTimeInMilliseconds + " " + reminderDayEnd);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startTimeInMilliseconds);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endTimeInMilliseconds);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, desc);
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, place);

    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=HOURLY;COUNT=1");
    values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);
    Uri eventUri;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
        eventUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
    } else {
        eventUri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");
    }
    // insert event to calendar
    Uri uri = cr.insert(eventUri, values);
    Log.e("EventTest", uri.toString());

    //add reminder for event
    try {
        Uri REMINDERS_URI;
        long id = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        ContentValues reminders = new ContentValues();
        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_ID, id);
        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD, CalendarContract.Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
        reminders.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.MINUTES, 1);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) {
            REMINDERS_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/reminders");
        } else {
            REMINDERS_URI = Uri.parse("content://calendar/reminders");
        }
        Uri remindersUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(REMINDERS_URI, reminders);
        //AsyncQueryHandler handler = new MyHandler(context.getContentResolver());
        //handler.startInsert(0, null, REMINDERS_URI, reminders);
        Log.e("RemindersTest", remindersUri.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What I want is add an event to calendar programmatically like when someone send you meeting invitation via email.

My device is samsung galaxy S6 with Android 7.0 (Nougat) OS. Please help me to do this.

Thankyou...

Comment: If I remember correctly, you should find correct calendar_id.
`values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);`
Why do you think, that id == 1?
I suppose, that it is not working, because id is incorrect.
You should get list of calendars first, and than find what actually do you need.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242472/retrieve-the-default-calendar-id-in-android

Comment: calendar_id = 1 means that we want to add the event to default calendar, is it correct or not? your suggestion please...

Comment: There is no guarantee that a calendar with `ID` 1 even exists. And if it exists, there is no guarantee that it's writeable.

Comment: Off topic: why do you even bother supporting Android 2.1 devices in your code?

Comment: Calendar id varies with devices, it's always good to get all calendars and choosing the one as per need